# Argument Type Mismatch -using Mapbox API

Tags: flutter, mapbox

Good day,

```
I am currently learning flutter under the Udemy course and at the moment is implementing maps in the app. The current lecture is using Google Maps to add markers on it when user taps on the screen, however I use a different API (Mapbox) and try to implement the same output.
```

Currently here is the issue I have encountered when I try to compile my code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxIf.png)

My code can be found here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';

import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:native_func_app/models/place.dart';

import '../models/place.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //const MapScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  final PlaceLocation initialLocation;
  final bool isSelecting;

  MapScreen({
    this.initialLocation =
        const PlaceLocation(latitude: 37.421, longitude: -122.084),
    this.isSelecting = false,
  });

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  LatLng _pickedLocation;

  void _selectLocation(LatLng position) {
    setState(() {
      _pickedLocation = position;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Map'),
      ),
      body: FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(widget.initialLocation.latitude,
              widget.initialLocation.longitude),
          zoom: 16.0,
          //onTap: widget.isSelecting ? _selectLocation: null,
          onTap: widget.isSelecting ? _selectLocation : () {},
        ),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate:
                  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/dhe/ckwd8qofr09gd14oq5d8djor9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGhlIiwiYSI6ImNrdnFybGw4ZzI1cWgycm91MXBpcW9oN3kifQ.fzK2_BFZrGU_vMpwTuU2Kg",
              /*subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            attributionBuilder: (_) {
              return Text("© OpenStreetMap contributors");
            },*/
              additionalOptions: {
                'accessToken':
                    'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGhlIiwiYSI6ImNrdnFybGw4ZzI1cWgycm91MXBpcW9oN3kifQ.fzK2_BFZrGU_vMpwTuU2Kg',
                'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8',
              }),
          MarkerLayerOptions(
            markers: _pickedLocation == null
                ? []
                : [
                    Marker(
                      point: _pickedLocation,
                      builder: (ctx) => Container(
                        child: FlutterLogo(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Right now, someone ask me to replace the null code with (){} to see if the error goes away and it does. However a new issue occurs when I recompile as seen here: [2nd issue crash at compile time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQucn.png)

Can anyone help me identify the issue?

If you need to access my project ill link the Github Project I am using to view the source codes:

https://github.com/DheDeveloperUsv/native_func_app

Any help or insight to resolve this issue is very much welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter `tapPosition` to your `_selectLocation`

```
void _selectLocation(TapPosition tapPosition, LatLng position) {
    setState(() {
      _pickedLocation = position;
    });
  }
```

onTap needs a function with 2 Parameters and no return value (`void`).
So this won't be working:

```
widget.isSelecting ? _selectLocation : () {}
```

`_selecteLocation` is a function this 1 parameter

and `(){}`  has no parameters. change `(){}` to `(TapPosition tapPosition, LatLng position){}`

complete code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';

import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:native_func_app/models/place.dart';

import '../models/place.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //const MapScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  final PlaceLocation initialLocation;
  final bool isSelecting;

  MapScreen({
    this.initialLocation =
        const PlaceLocation(latitude: 37.421, longitude: -122.084),
    this.isSelecting = false,
  });

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  LatLng _pickedLocation;

  void _selectLocation(TapPosition tapPosition, LatLng position) {
    setState(() {
      _pickedLocation = position;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Map'),
      ),
      body: FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(widget.initialLocation.latitude,
              widget.initialLocation.longitude),
          zoom: 16.0,
          //onTap: widget.isSelecting ? _selectLocation: null,
          onTap: widget.isSelecting ? _selectLocation : (TapPosition tapPosition, LatLng position) {},
        ),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate:
                  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/dhe/ckwd8qofr09gd14oq5d8djor9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGhlIiwiYSI6ImNrdnFybGw4ZzI1cWgycm91MXBpcW9oN3kifQ.fzK2_BFZrGU_vMpwTuU2Kg",
              /*subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            attributionBuilder: (_) {
              return Text("© OpenStreetMap contributors");
            },*/
              additionalOptions: {
                'accessToken':
                    'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGhlIiwiYSI6ImNrdnFybGw4ZzI1cWgycm91MXBpcW9oN3kifQ.fzK2_BFZrGU_vMpwTuU2Kg',
                'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8',
              }),
          MarkerLayerOptions(
            markers: _pickedLocation == null
                ? []
                : [
                    Marker(
                      point: _pickedLocation,
                      builder: (ctx) => Container(
                        child: FlutterLogo(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this code, and added the library for position_tap_detector_2 as it is not recognizing TapDetector outside the FlutterMap widget. When the same parsing issue occured, i tried flutter clean and the code successfully compile. However some of the map API was not connected to my initial screen and I need to  revisit some of the flutter widgets to restore some of the missing functions of the app. Ill try to message back when the whole thing is restore. Thank you for your reply and code for guidance